# Cakephp, modify auth class's behavior when the user is not logged in

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

By default the cakephp Auth class redirects the viewer to the front page if he/she is not logged in and tries to access a denied page.

I wish for the server to run some code when this happens (set some variables and stuff). How would I go about modifying the Auth class's behavior when it redirects the user to the home page due to lack of authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first it is no good idea to change the Auth-Component-code itself since in an update you would loose all your changes.

You should write your own component which extends the built-in component like this:

```
// /app/controllers/components/my_auth.php
App::import('Component', 'Auth');
class MyAuthComponent extends AuthComponent {
    function redirect($url = null) {
        //have a look in the original auth-component to see how to change this behaviour
    }
}
```

This way you can now use your new component with your extended redirect-method.

Unfortunately you would now have to change each `$this->Auth` to `$this->MyAuth`. If you do not want that you can do something like this in your AppController:

```
public function constructClasses() {
    parent::constructClasses();
    $this->Auth = $this->MyAuth;
}
```

Comment: This is technically incorrect. The redirect() function is not actually called when an invalid page is reached. It is used to determine where to redirect to after a successful login. However, extending AuthComponent and overloading the relevant functions did solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the sounds of your question, you need to specify your app's allowed actions, then test for authentication and call your method if users are not logged in. Place in AppController if you want this to be application-wide.

Auth::user() returns null if the user is not logged in.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    var $components = array('Auth', 'Session');

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your app-wide beforeFilter code, if any
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view', 'register', 'whatever');
        if ($this->Auth->user() == null) {
            $this->_attemptRestricted();
        }
    }

    function _attemptRestricted() {
        // set your variables, etc...
    }
}
```

All of Auth's defaults can be customized as your application requires.

For more about Auth::user() --
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1264/user

All about AuthComponent --
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication

Comment: Cool this is exactly what i was looking for. So far I have been allowing every single action and then using an if else logic inside the action to handle redirects.

Comment: The problem now is that `__attemptRestricted()` will run on every page, even those that are allowed with `$this->Auth->allow()`

Comment: If you set $this->Auth->authorize to 'controller', you can filter allowed / denied in the isAuthortized() method: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1275/authorize